# How can i define my error pages in CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have rails 3.2.6 and BrowserCMS my application Error pages(404, 500) in public folder, but i need to define my Page Not Found, Access denied, Internal server error page in BrowserCMS.  `# Exception are redirected to local routes

    config.exceptions_app = self.routes`
 i did this in my application.rb file.  it's not working. Is there any other way for this?